# Prime number into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I try to do a function in order to sort an array and display after that only the prime number. But all the elements of my array are random numbers, and the problem is that the function display only negative prime numbers and not positive like 7 and 3, what can I do in order to solve the problem

```
int prime_arr(int size, int *arr, int *sort_arr)
{
    int i, j, k = 0, flag;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 2; j < arr[i]/2; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] % j == 0){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0){
            sort_arr[k++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: your function doesn't look like it displays anything at all

Comment: There is clearly not enough information for anybody to see what you are doing since the code references arrays whose initializations are not shown.

Comment: No I have another function who is a display function. This is just a sort function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 problems with the code:
1. You should return k, not j.  k is the size of sort_arr
2. You should loop until arr[i] / 2, not one less than that (see <= in code below)
3. You do not handle negative numbers. Change your loop to the following:

```
for (j = 2; j <= abs(arr[i])/2; j++)
```

Without the code that prints your values, I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully fixing these will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks I fix the problem